# CustomGroup Create API Not Passing Param extends_entity_column_id

Tags: custom-fields, api

I am using the API to create a custom group that extends "Participant". I want to set it to be based on Participant (Event Type).

I set the "extends_entity_column_value" and "extends_entity_column_id".
However, it does not seem to pass the "extends_entity_column_id" parameter on the call.

Here is the call I am making:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('CustomGroup', 'create', array(
  'debug' => 1,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'title' => "Membership Bible Training",
  'extends' => "Participant",
  'collapse_adv_display' => 1,
  'extends_entity_column_id' => 3,
  'extends_entity_column_value' => 19,
));
```

Here is the result of the call:

```
{

"is_error": 0,
"undefined_fields": [
    "style",
    "is_active",
    "title",
    "collapse_adv_display",
    "extends_entity_column_id",
    "extends_entity_column_value",
    "extends"
],
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"id": 79,
"values": [
    {
        "id": "79",
        "name": "Membership_Bible_Training",
        "title": "Membership Bible Training",
        "extends": "Participant",
        "extends_entity_column_id": "",
        "extends_entity_column_value": [
            "19"
        ],
        "style": "Inline",
        "collapse_display": "",
        "help_pre": "",
        "help_post": "",
        "weight": "1",
        "is_active": "1",
        "table_name": "civicrm_value_membership_bible_training_79",
        "is_multiple": "",
        "min_multiple": "",
        "max_multiple": "",
        "collapse_adv_display": "1",
        "created_id": "",
        "created_date": "",
        "is_reserved": ""
    }
]
```

}

Notice how "extends_entity_column_id" is empty. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

You have to set

```
'extends' => "ParticipantEventType",
```

By doing that it will set the proper value for 'extends_entity_column_id'.